# Primefaces - all inplaces toggled when validation fail

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces

I am using JSF 2.1 and primefaces 3.5. Let's say I have a following code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
        "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
      xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
      xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
      xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">
<h:head>
  <title>Web application</title>
</h:head>
<h:body>
    <h1>Editor</h1>
    <h:form>
    <p:wizard>
        <p:tab title="Edit">
            <h2>Edit:</h2>
            <p:dataTable value="#{editorBean.applications}" var="app">
                <p:column headerText="Id">
                    <p:inplace emptyLabel="Value not assigned" editor="true" effectSpeed="fast">
                        <p:inputText value="#{app.id}" />
                    </p:inplace>
                </p:column>
                <p:column headerText="Name">
                    <p:inplace emptyLabel="Value not assigned" editor="true" effectSpeed="fast">
                        <p:inputText value="#{app.name}" required="true" />
                    </p:inplace>
                </p:column>
            </p:dataTable>
        </p:tab>
        <p:tab title="Summary">
            <h2>Summary:</h2>
            <p:dataTable value="#{editorBean.applications}" var="app">
                <p:column headerText="Id">#{app.id}</p:column>
                <p:column headerText="Name">#{app.name}</p:column>
            </p:dataTable>
        </p:tab>
    </p:wizard>
    </h:form>
</h:body>
</html>
```

When I press next on the wizard, and validation fails (application name is blank) then all inplaces included on the page are toggled to editor mode.
I think that they shouldn't be toggled since validation for each input is performed when you  accept editor for this input.

[image: screenshot]

It looks awful, especially that I have a lot of inplaces.

I would like to disable toggling of each inplace editor when validation fails. Does anyone have an idea of how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because of `p:inplace` component is not made for this usage purpose. There are few other components makes problems when used in data tables like inplace but for your requirement this can be useful:

```
<p:column headerText="Year" style="width:25%">
        <p:cellEditor>
            <f:facet name="output"><h:outputText value="#{car.year}" /></f:facet>
            <f:facet name="input"><p:inputText value="#{car.year}" style="width:96%"     label="Year"/></f:facet>
        </p:cellEditor>
</p:column>
```

You can check the full example from [primefaces showcase](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase-labs/ui/datatableCellEditing.jsf).

Comment: What if I would like to do edition in <p:rowExpansion>? It is impossible to use <p:cellEditor> there.